# How to save custom dataset in local folder

Tags: python, huggingface, huggingface-datasets

I have created a custom huggingface dataset, containing images and ground truth data coming from json lines file. I want to save it to a local folder and be able to use it as is by loading it after to other notebooks. I did not find out how this can happen.

```
DatasetDict({
    train: Dataset({
        features: ['image', 'id', 'ground_truth'],
        num_rows: 7
    })
    test: Dataset({
        features: ['image', 'id', 'ground_truth'],
        num_rows: 4
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [huggingface documentacion](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/package_reference/main_classes#datasets.Dataset.save_to_disk) you can use `save_to_disk` which "saves a dataset to a dataset directory, or in a filesystem".

Example:

```
ds.save_to_disk("path/to/dataset/dir")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a very easy way to do it in [this](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/v1.12.0/process.html) documentation:

```
dataset.save_to_disk("path-to-dataset")
```